# SOAP in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, .net-core

How you do SOAP in .NET Core? Are there any equivalents of [Apache CXF](https://cxf.apache.org/) in .Net Core (not just a simple SOAP client but full featured stack)?

Sorry if this is a very basic question, my search so far doesn't yield any clear answer.

Comment: WCF client side support is included, but there would be no server side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In VS 2017, as of December '17 (v15.5) you can now add a generated WCF client to a service using WSDL from a .NET Standard project using Connected Services. In the Solution Explorer, you can get there from a right-click on "Dependencies" or right-click on the project under "Add..."

Answer (score 14):

Microsoft currently does not plan to ship a SOAP server side framework for .NET Core. Neither the WCF ServiceHost nor ASMX are available. Too early to tell, which of the non-Microsoft stacks will jump in and be the dominant player.

With the introduction of ASP.NET Web API and the uprising of REST endpoints, WCF was dead. The WCF client is a interop story, not a forward going story (full story here: http://blog.tonysneed.com/2016/01/06/wcf-is-dead-long-live-mvc-6/)

Comment: This is kinda sad, since for some cases, SOAP is still superior for backend communication between services.

Comment: Sad it is. Nevertheless, for a NEW stack (which Core essentially is) it is the right decision. REST takes over as SOAP killed CORBA and RPC before. But a little bit support for existing environment and policies would have been nice.

Comment: I read this many times. But WCF is not just SOAP! I can understand replacement of SOAP by the REST, but what about streams, named pipes, tcp, duplex etc.? REST will never catch these...

Comment: Agree. However, only 10% of usage. And in 2017 heterogeneous world, these do not fit either.

Comment: Microsoft is asking for feedback on this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/whereismysolution/2017/09/08/we-want-your-feedback/

Comment: @Fanda look close to SignalR Core regards async messaging. They are brewing something there.

Answer (score 6):

Some months ago, due to a limitation WCF clients have (when integrating with a Java Web Service, someone created a response class with the same name as the method and in the same namespace and when the WCF client was sending a request it failed the serialization - can't find the related question in SO) I had to create a SOAP HTTP client that used underline the HttpClient. I eventually released an open source version (https://github.com/gravity00/SimpleSOAPClient) that we are successfully using in production and supports .NET Core and Xamarin applications. Feel free to give it a try. I recommend version 2.0.0-RC03 due to some major improvements since version 1.x.

Comment: I've been looking for a working solution to not having access to consuming soap services and stumbled on your project, however the examples and tutorial don't seem to mesh with the library. Is this a v1.x vs 2.x issue?

Comment: Hi @Marqueone, I can try to help you with that. Feel free to open a GitHub issue with a code sample so I can give it a look.

Comment: This is a good project. The only issue i had is that the svcutil generated classes i got have no XmlRoot attributes and so serialization with it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Here u have a little trick I used targeting **"framework 452"** in an ASP.Net 5.0 Web App.

Unfortunately the new **"Add connected service" -> "WCF service"** only works when targeting **".Net Core"**, so I created a basic console app with same name as my web app.

Console apps allow to add **"Service reference"**. Once added **VS2015** creates all service references in folder **"Service References"**.

Just move folder contents to Web solution and use a client constructor that accepts `HttpBindings` and `EndPoint`parameters.

In my case I'm connecting to **Echosign** service initializing client as follows:

```
using (EchoSignDocumentService16PortTypeClient service = new EchoSignDocumentService16PortTypeClient(new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport), new EndpointAddress(adddress)))
{
...
}
```

Comment: ServiceModel doesn't exist in .net core though

Comment: "...only works when targeting '.Net Core'..." Should be noted that while searches are probably taking folks here, the OP _was_ only asking about .NET Core.

Answer (score 1):

I need SOAP for my legacy clients, so I created a separate SOAP library that is compatible with my legacy clients, using .NET framework, hosted in a separate environment. (SOAP.mywebsite.com). Then on www.mywebsite.com (created with asp.net Core, I have a rest interface. The SOAP layer calls the rest interface. 
The library to call the rest interface is generated using Swashbuckle.

Answer (score 0):

To get around this problem....I created a nuget package in .Net 4.5 connecting to native SOAP clients not supported in .NET Core. Next I created a .Net core application targeting the .net framework. This allowed me to use the nuget package without errors.