# Issue in consuming a asmx web method

Tags: c#, web-services, console-application, asmx

I am creating a simple asmx web service and trying to consume them. Below is the asmx web service

```
public class AddTwoNumbers : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public int GetSum(int a, int b)
    {
        return  a + b;
    }
}
```

This is the Windows Console application where I am consuming the service that was created

```
 namespace TestASMXService
 {
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AddingNumber.AddTwoNumbers add = new AddingNumber.AddTwoNumbers();
        Console.Write("First Number:");
        int firstNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Second Number:");
        int secNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write ("The Sum is:",add.GetSum(firstNum, secNum));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

It receives the user inputs and does not return any result or throws any error

[image]

Can anyone please tell me what I am missing here.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why ASMX?

Comment: I am just learning about asmx. and trying to see how to consume the web methods

Comment: ASMX is deprecated, if not obsolete - if you want to learn about web-services I suggest you using ASP.NET Web API. ASMX shouldn't be used for new projects because it isn't supported by ASP.NET Core: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35830341/159145

Comment: Yes I have done couple learning exercises in the Web API's. But can you please say if there is anything wrong with the above code

Comment: I cannot see anything immediately wrong - I suspect it's a runtime configuration issue. Are you sure the ASMX service is running and accessible? If your proxy class was generated by Visual Studio you should be able to step-in to the `GetSum` call and see where it's blocking - I suspect it's blocking on getting the response. Are you running any firewall software that's blocking local-loopback connections?

Comment: I tested my web service in SoapUI and it returns the response there but not in the consumed Console application

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass an argument in the Console.Write, but do not have a placeholder for it in the format string. The method GetSum will therefore not be called.

Change it to:

```
Console.Write("The Sum is: {0}", add.GetSum(firstNum, secNum));
```