# Soap based web service to .Net Core Service conversion

Tags: c#, .net

Is this possible to convert existing soap based web service to .net core service via some tool or code?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to host a SOAP service in .NET core.
Also answered here: [SOAP in .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35682728/soap-in-net-core)