# How can i use protocol Soap when is not including in Formatters namespace?

Tags: c#, .net

I´m trying to use soap protocol including from using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.soap but visual studio throws a message saying soap does n´t  exist in this the namespace and the intelli sense helper only show me Binary format. How can i add this class or what can i do?

I´m using .net framerwork 4.7.03 with  visual  studio community 2019 in language c# running on w10.

```
using System;

using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap;

static class Program
    {  
        static void Main()
        {          
        }
    }
```

I expect that i can use soap format correctly to serialize and unserialize in my web service

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.soap?view=netframework-4.8 : "When building applications that uses the types in this namespace, you must reference the System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.dll assembly"

Answer (score 1):

Is your project .NET Core?  This appears to be a design decision with .NET Core; [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35682728/soap-in-net-core) may be relevant.  Additional evidence: Create a new console app with the .NET Framework (not .NET Core), add a Reference, search Assemblies, and System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap is in the list.

Comment: They say in the question they are using .Net Framework 4.7